# Impacts on Page Layouts, Record Types, Objects and Fields on Profiles Clean Up

Tags: apex, permissions, profile, sharing

Since the Salesforce org becomes old, there is a need for Clean up.

On this process, looking to clean up the profiles in the org.

I have already created an Administrative User report to check the Active and Inactive User counts for each profile. This is very helpful to clean up the profiles which are not assigned to any Active Users.

Also, am thinking of reducing the number of profiles count to 30 to 35 from 91. So, I may need to delete some of the unwanted profiles.

Now my question is if the deleting profile is having access to some page layouts, record types, objects, fields, etc. What will be the impact?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. Removing profiles does not cascade-delete or otherwise affect page layouts, record types, objects, or fields.

You may see impact in other ways. For example, it's possible that your org has Validation Rules, or even Apex code, in place that looks for specific Profile names or Profile Ids. Because such references don't form a static dependency, Salesforce will not stop you from deleting such Profiles, but Validation Rules will cease to work as expected, and Apex code and unit tests may fail and require remediation.

I'd suggest making your changes in a Full Copy sandbox first and performing a regression test process, as well as executing all Apex unit tests following the deletion, to reduce the scope of potential impact.

You can start to identify areas of concern by searching across your metadata in an IDE. The things I would prioritize are

- References to `Profile.Id`, `ProfileId`, `Profile.Name`. This'll help you find areas where you have problematic direct references.
- Secondarily, the Names and Ids of the affected profiles to be deleted.